# > Task :react-native-wifi-reborn:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED (React-Native)

Tags: react-native, wifi

I have installed [react-native-wifi-reborn](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-wifi-reborn) and when run `react-native run-android` I get the above mentioned error:

```
> Task :react-native-wifi-reborn:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

................................................................................



le.java:27: error: cannot find symbol

import com.reactlibrary.rnwifi.errors.GetCurrentWifiSSIDErrorCodes;
```

Adding the Image of my Android Studio:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I don't know what to do next!!

I need help!!
Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the config but not in **Android Studio** I just changed this file **GetCurrentWifiSSIDErrorCodes** extension from `.kt` to `.java` and added this:

```
package com.reactlibrary.rnwifi.errors;

public enum GetCurrentWifiSSIDErrorCodes {
    /**
     * Not connected or connecting.
     */
    CouldNotDetectSSID,
}
```

But later I got another error `> Task :app:processDebugManifest FAILED`

I got the solution I referred this answer [#issuecomment-461852948](https://github.com/wmcmahan/react-native-calendar-events/issues/213#issuecomment-461852948).
Also, the answer is discussed [here](https://github.com/JuanSeBestia/react-native-wifi-reborn/issues/153#issuecomment-759436869).
Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

I solved it.

[GetCurrentWifiSSIDErrorCodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8aNj.png) is not java file.
Configure it from Android Studio.

You can see configure button on top of the window if you open that file.

That's all.

[Would you like to click here?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxz0w.png)

Comment: I have located the file. But not getting how to configure.. Please Help!!

Comment: It is asking for a template to select.